# clearing all markers / view in RVIZ remotely

Tags: ros, rviz, visualization-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm drawing a lot of markers in rviz to visualize the outcome of an algorithm. As I'm often interrupting/killing it, it's infeasible to keep track of what has been drawn in order to delete it later. Is there any possibility to send something like "wipe" or "clear" to rviz to clear all markers? Currently, I'm sending a message with many markers with `action=DELETE` but that seems a bit brute force. Is there any better option?

Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53595/clearing-all-markers-/-view-in-rviz-remotely/) by [Markus Achtelik](https://answers.ros.org/users/867/markus-achtelik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 390 on 2013-01-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are setting markers fairly frequently, perhaps you could set an appropriate **lifetime** in the [Marker message](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker#The_Marker_Message).

Then, **rviz** would erase them after you kill your node.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus Achtelik](https://answers.ros.org/users/867/markus-achtelik/) on 2013-01-30**:
Thanks, that could be a workaround. I Just have to think about something when I get a coffee and the algorithm finished in the meantime... ;) It seems there is no other solution (yet)?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-01-30**:
The usual solution is to re-use the marker.ns and marker.id values of the obsolete markers, which automatically deletes them as a side-effect.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recommend to use `DELETE_ALL`, is simpler and no brute force is required. Here is a snippet:

```
from visualization_msgs.msg import Marker, MarkerArray
...
marker_array_msg = MarkerArray()
marker = Marker()
marker.id = 0
marker.ns = self.marker_ns
marker.action = Marker.DELETEALL
marker_array_msg.markers.append(marker)
self.marker_array_pub.publish(marker_array_msg)
rospy.sleep(0.2)
```

---

Originally posted by [Oscar Lima](https://answers.ros.org/users/21475/oscar-lima/) with karma: 831 on 2021-04-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [labude](https://answers.ros.org/users/103641/labude/) on 2023-03-12**:
This solution is especially helpful if the number of markers in the array changes from message to message because the 're-using marker.id' solution from the comment above can't be applied in this case.